# How to open and work on a newly opened overlapping folder or program while another folder/program is running in a maximum screen mode

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I am facing a problem while taking sreenshoots on a folder/program opened in a maximum mode/screen. Everytime when I opened snipshoot programme from taskbar, it will get minimized after the mouse movement from taskbar. ***Alt+Shift*** can select screenshoots/overlapped programs and works fine for me. But everytime when you do this than this is no more comfortable. I searched a lot and not not find any effective solutions. The problem can be captured as follows:

[image: A portrait of the problem]

I badly need a solution so that everytime I don't need to fix this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution!!
Steps to solve the issues:

1. Type Control Panel in Windows Search to launch Control Panel.
2. Click on Ease of Access Center from the list.
3. Click on Make the mouse easier to use option under Explore all settings
4. Uncheck the box beside “Activate the window by hovering over it with
   the mouse” Restart the PC and check.

   [The Details solution is here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/screen-disappear-when-i-move-my-mouse-to-click-on/e43232bc-bffe-4a4a-96dc-b36d7a16e3ad)